# Unrecognized backslash escape in kotlin regex

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

I'm trying to implement regex to my android app in Kotlin.
Regex I use is: [https://regexr.com/46ljf](http://regexr.com/46ljf)

Try 1:

```
val myRegex= """/()\\mCi=[0-9]*/g"""
val regex = sb.toString().toRegex()
var res= regex.find(value.toString())!!
if(res!= null) {
  Log.d("###regex", res.value)
}
```

Try 2:

```
val sb = StringBuilder()
sb.append("/()")
sb.append("\\")
sb.append("mCi=[0-9]*/g")

val regex = sb.toString().toRegex()
var res= regex.find(value.toString())!!
if(res!= null) {
  Log.d("###regex", res.value)
}
```

In this case my regex string is ok, but error is:

> "Unrecognized backslash escape sequence in pattern near index 5"

I was also trying other things but no luck.

Comment: What are your expectations? Return a single result, `mCi=268435455`?

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript-flavored regex? Remove the starting `/` and ending `/g`, and if you expect a match group, you need to move the parenthesis

Comment: Also, your regex has an empty capture group and requires `\\mCi=1234` to match -- raw string backslashes are just `\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to match `mCi=268435455`, a single match in the input string.

The main problem is that you are using a regex literal notation inside a string literal. The regex delimiters and flags are parsed as part of the regex pattern and thus you have no match. In the first snippet, you are not even using `myRegex`.

Use

```
val regex = """mCi=[0-9]*""".toRegex()
val s = "CellInfoLte:{mRegistered=NO mTimeStampType=unknown mTimeStamp=0ns CellIdentityLte:{ mMcc=219 mMnc=1 mCi=268435455 mPci=453 mTac=65535 mEarfcn=1501} CellSignalStrengthLte: ss=37 rsrp=-104 rsrq=-15 rssnr=2147483647 cqi=2147483647 ta=2147483647}"
var res = regex.find(s)?.value
println(res) // => mCi=268435455
```

See the [Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/VTEKT41059).

If you plan to only get the digit part of `mCi`, you may use

```
val regex = """(?<=mCi=)[0-9]*""".toRegex()
```

The `(?<=mCi=)` positive lookbehind will require the presence of `mCi=` immediately before the 0 or more digits, but will be excluded from the matched text. See [this Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/ZDOB39305).